# Install actual android device not just skin on Android Studio/Virtual Machine

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, virtual-machine

I am trying to run some tests of an Android application I am developing. The question I have is if it is possible to create an actual android device with its settings not just skins and the device's layout using Android Studio or a Virtual Machine, in order to see how application operates on other devices.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: You can use android `Emulator` or use third-party emulator like `GenyMotion` or use your real android device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AVD Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) in Android Studio. You can create Android VM with it. You can customize :

- What Android Version runs on it
- The device screen size
- memory
- camera
- storage

You can send custom inputs

- Physically moving the device
- Custom GPS coordinates
- Send sms and call
- Change battery level
- etc

It is more than a skin, you can access the file system with adb, navigates the settings etc.

What you can't do is having the custom software layers made by manufacturers (i.e. OneUI from Samsung). It is stock Android

Answer (score 0):

The emulator seems to be a standard `qemu` running a complete android system, so it's not only a skin.

If you want to test on real devices, you can have a look at [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/overview), which offers actual devices for testing, for a fee. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/available-testing-devices on how to get the list of devices. Another option is [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/physical-mobile-devices), which seems free for open source projects.